# React-sortable-hoc transition doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I made a sortable list using react-sortable-hoc. My problem is that there is no transition. I tried to use transitionDuration, but it still doesnt work. Here is sandbox with problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hill-lulln?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What type of transition you want?

Comment: Just smooth like here: http://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/basic-configuration/drag-handle?_k=1jrh6b

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your SortableItem in List

```
    const SortableItem = sortableElement(({ value, index }) => (
    <li style={{"listStyleType":'none'}}>
    << YOUR CODE HERE>>
    </li>
  ));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).